# Attribute error 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I wrote a code to get the year month and day in int from input and used datetime.. Date() to convert it into date format.

My code:

```
import datetime 

y= int(input())     
m= int(input())     
d= int(input()) 

dob = datetime.date(y,m, d) 

print(dob)
```

The error which I received is

```
Attribute error : datetime.date object has no attribute 'date'
```

How do I solve this ?

Comment: Are you sure, this is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you something important. There is no `date` attribute on that datetime module.

Try importing like this instead,

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: The error message is indeed telling something important, note the: `datetime.date object has no attribute 'date'`. 
This indicates that the function called is actually `datetime.date.date` and not `datetime.date`